# Magento 2 how to extend core module

Tags: magento2, controllers, extend

I want to add a button to `abc.com/customer/account` page when the user click it, it will redirect to a new page e.g. `customer/account/upgrademember`. How can I do this? I find it difficult to route it to my module. In `Magento_Customer` module, the `\Magento\Customer\etc\frontend\route.xml` defines when the frontName is customer, Magento will go to `Magento_Customer` module. But I create a new Controller `upgrademember.php` in my module. How can the Magento go to my `upgrademember.php` when the user clicks the `abc.com/ccustomer/account/upgrademember`.?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I got another solution. It is adding `routes.xml` under `etc/frontend`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
   <router id="standard">
        <route id="customer" frontName="customer">
            <module name="Namespace_ModuleName" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

It will redirect the upgrade `abc.com/ccustomer/account/upgrademember` to the my custom module's controller `UpgradeMember.php`

Comment: will this override the customer module frontname or just extend this with our custom route ? what about the priority of the route if the same class exist in both module ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.
In your module add this in `di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\Router\ActionList\Reader">
    <plugin name="namespace-module-route" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Plugin\ActionListReader" sortOrder="100" />
</type>
```

then create the file `Namespace/Module/Model/Plugin/ActionListReader.php` with this content:

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Plugin;

class ActionListReader
{
    public function afterRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Router\ActionList\Reader\Interceptor $subject, $actions)
    {
        $actions['magento\customer\controller\account\upgrademember'] = 'Namespace\Module\Controller\Customer\Account\Upgrademember'; //your class name should go here.
        return $actions;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried, but it failed to plugin Magento\Framework\App\Router\ActionList\Reader, since I added a error_log() in afterRead(), but it logged nothing. Thanks.

Comment: @ricky :- post your code

Comment: @Pradeep Kumar I use phpstorm to write the plugin, phpstorm shows 'cannot resolve symbol' error on  <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Router\ActionList\Reader"> and 'undefined namespace' error on public function afterRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Router\ActionList\Reader\Interceptor $subject, $actions) Also, I can't find the file at [lib](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.0.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Router).

Comment: this does not work in M2.2, class does not exist and i have not found the usage of it in any of the core module.