# Add new action to existing module, routing

Tags: magento2, module, router, action

I am trying to add a new action to the existing module `Magento_Customer`.

My module has the following namespace `Custom_AccountReferral`

I need to add a new action `customer/account/referral/`

I have create a custom module and it works.

1. Create a new controller inside my module directory `AccountReferral/Controller/Account` the file with name `Referral.php`
2. Create the `routes.xml` file inside `etc/frontend/` directory

With the following content

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="customer" frontName="customer">
            <module name="Custom_AccountReferral" before="Magento_Customer"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

3. Also tried to add the following line to the `di.xml` file

   preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Referral" type="Custom\AccountReferral\Controller\Account\Referral"/>

But unfortunately it still gives me the 404 page

```
Whoops, our bad...
```

Please suggest how to add a new action to existing module routes.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

The content of the `Referral` file

```
namespace Custom\AccountReferral\Controller\Account;
class Referral extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount {

    protected $customerRepository;

    protected $dataObjectHelper;
    protected $session;

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
    ) {
        $this->session            = $customerSession;
        $this->resultPageFactory  = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->dataObjectHelper   = $dataObjectHelper;
        parent::__construct( $context );
    }

    public function execute() {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock( 'customer_account_dashboard_referral_edit' );
        if ( $block ) {
            $block->setRefererUrl( $this->_redirect->getRefererUrl() );
        }

        $data               = $this->session->getCustomerFormData( true );
        $customerId         = $this->session->getCustomerId();
        $customerDataObject = $this->customerRepository->getById( $customerId );
        if ( ! empty( $data ) ) {
            $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
                $customerDataObject,
                $data,
                \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface::class
            );
        }
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set( __( 'Referral Settings' ) );

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

This is just an example, I haven't added any logic yet, because it is not accessible.

Comment: Why name your action `Pgp` you have this action in directory ?

Comment: @EvgeniyKapelko sorry this was a type, I have edited my question

Comment: show me Referral.php

Comment: @EvgeniyKapelko, I have updated my answer

Comment: Where is namespace?

Comment: @EvgeniyKapelko I have updated it, please have a look

Comment: @EvgeniyKapelko omg, you are awesome !!! I have found an error in my namespace, please paste your comment as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: Please change your inherit

Comment: Did you forget to mention the namespace?

Comment: @EvgeniyKapelko Yes I had a typo in my namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inherit this way; Replace this code .

```
namespace Custom\AccountReferral\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Referral;

class extends Referral 
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: mmm can you explain better why?

Answer (score 1):

Starting on as you say that your module works, your controller should be in this path :

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Controller/Account/Custom // Account/Custom
>   is for exemple

The content should be something like this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Account;

class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $_registry;
    protected $_pageConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $pageConfig
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_pageConfig = $pageConfig;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute() {
        echo "My controller works fine !";
    }
}
```

Now you can call your controller like this : `baseurl/frontname/foldercontroller/filecontroller`

**IMPORTANT:**

To add a new action in core module `Magento_Customer` you need to extend first that module then you add what you need, I see that you are using `customer` as frontName in you **xml** and this frontName 'custom' is already reserved ! you can use it again if you extend his module.

See this to how extend an exsting core module : [Magento 2 how to extend core module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93458/magento-2-how-to-extend-core-module)

Good luck.